# How to render an edit form based on a many to many field

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I make an edit form that displays a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with the fields that the user has chosen as already filled up?

I have a field called items in a model which is a `ManyToManyField` and in the form I am using the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to render it, but when I used `{{ form.items }}` in the edit form, then the choices that the user has already chosen are not displayed.

How do I mark the already chosen fields as chosen in the multi select box that is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating a form, you could pass initial values for the fields.

You could do something like

```
form = Form(initial={'items':<items_queryset>.values('id', flat=True)})
```

or if you're using a model form, you could pass a model instance

```
form = Form(instance=model_instance)
```

Source: [dynamic initial values in django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)